# Why is my TextView null, altough im getting the values from the Database?

Tags: java, exception, null

I wanted to get the comments for my social network app from the database and show it on a recycler view but the text where the comment should be is null
and i dont know why.

//The Database Reference

```
PostsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Posts").child(Post_Key).child("Comments");

protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Comments, CommentsViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter
                = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Comments, CommentsViewHolder>
                (
                        Comments.class,
                        R.layout.all_comments_layout,
                        CommentsViewHolder.class,
                        PostsRef
                )
        {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(CommentsViewHolder viewHolder, Comments model, int position)
            {
                viewHolder.setUsername(model.getUsername());
                viewHolder.setComment(model.getComment());
                viewHolder.setDate(model.getDate());
                viewHolder.setTime(model.getTime());
            }
        };

        CommentsList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

    }
```

//I think heres the problem

```
    public static class CommentsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {
        View mView;

        public CommentsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView)
        {
            super(itemView);

            mView = itemView;
        }

        public void setUsername(String username)
        {
            TextView myUserName = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.comment_username);
            myUserName.setText("@" + username + "  ");
        }

        public void setComment(String comment)
        {
            TextView myComment = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.comment_text);
            myComment.setText(" :" + comment);
        }

        public void setDate(String date)
        {
            TextView myDate = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.comment_date);
            myDate.setText("  Date: " + date);
        }

        public void setTime(String time)
        {
            TextView myTime = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.comment_time);
            myTime.setText("  Time: " + time);
        }
    }
```

//And this is my static class

```
public class Comments
{
    public String comment, date, time, username;

    public Comments()
    {

    }

    public Comments(String comment, String date, String time, String username) {
        this.comment = comment;
        this.date = date;
        this.time = time;
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

Anyone has a solution for this or can tell me where's my mistake?
im relatively new to programming in java so yeah..

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by renaming comment to comments because in the database it is comments but i misread it.